# Why is 0 == [], but 0 == false and ![] == false?

Tags: javascript

At least in JavaScript the following are true:

```
0 == []       // true
0 == false    // true
![] == false  // true
```

Why is that? I know that `==` means equals but not equals in type, but how is `false == true`, so to speak, in that case?

Comment: `[]` as a string is "", and false as a number is 0

Comment: Where are you getting `[] == true`, because it should be `false`

Comment: @Matt Burland, type into the console "console.log(![])", it returns "false"

Comment: `[] == false` on the console returns `true`.

Comment: @FrederikWitte: That is absolutely not the same thing as what you typed in your question. `[] == true` and `![]` are not the same operation

Comment: Since no one has mentioned it yet - go look up JavaScript Type Coercion

Comment: Nutshell: because JavaScript.

Comment: in practice, the casting actually makes sense, but in contrived examples it looks silly.

Comment: Firstly: Sorry, then I got something else wrong also, secondly: edited the question now...

Comment: When mixing types, the JavaScript `==` operator is not guaranteed to be *transitive*.

Comment: Could someone probably provide a topic where I can read on why (!something == false) != (something == true)? Because I don't quite understand

Comment: http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.9.3

Comment: A simple example that might clarify the issue: `2 == true` is false and `3 == true` is false but obviously `2 == 3` is also false. If two things are falsey (or truthy) it doesn't mean they are equal.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp

Comment: @Matt Burland, I don't know, if this is another stupid question, but if you type into the console console.log(Boolean([])); it returns true...?

Comment: @FrederikWitte Because that's the definition of the function: **"If value is omitted or is 0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined, or the empty string (""), the object has an initial value of false. All other values, including any object or the string "false", create an object with an initial value of true."**

Comment: @DaveNewton Woops, thanks for clearing that up... I think I've had enough of JS for this evening

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript coerces objects to boolean values when using the non-strict equality operator.

```
0 == []
```

because JavaScript coerces both of the values (both of which are **not** of the same type) to boolean values to compare them.  In other words, `false == false`.

If you use `===`, on the other hand, you're checking object equality.

An interesting use case would be this:

```
[] === []; // => false
```

This is because `===` is checking the memory location of the objects. Two arrays don't share the same memory location. However:

```
var arr = [];

arr === arr; // ==> true
```

But, here's another interesting twist:

```
1 === 1; // ==> true
```

In the case of arrays and plain objects, JavaScript references the memory location. But with values like strings and numbers, JavaScript checks whether the values are absolutely equal with the `===` operator.

So the big difference comes down to differences in `==` and `===`, and how JavaScript coerces types.

**Hint**: This is why it's usually recommended that you use the strict `===` operator if you need to prevent coercion (however, sometimes coercion can work to your benefit, for example when working with cross-browser issues where a value might be `undefined` in one browser but `null` in the other browser. Then you can say something like `!!thatStrangeValue`, and both `undefined` and `null` will be coerced to the same thing).

## Edit

OP brought up a good point:

```
[] == false;
![] == false;
```

The above statements are both correct, which is strange. I would say the first statement is checking for emptiness, while the second one is checking for existence. Anyone know the answer to this last point?

Comment: Excellent and well-thought out post. It's important to remember though that there is a difference between equality and strict equality. This can be challenging to newcomers sometimes

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the insights, but it misses one point, why is ![] == false, when 0 == []?

Comment: @FrederikWitte, thanks. Yes you make a good point. I edited my answer to give a specific example of where the hang-up is. I'm not exactly sure what the answer to that last point is, though.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, there are two types of equality. There is equality of value which is represented by `==` and equality of value and type, which is represented by `===`. The latter is the strict equality operator.

In your case, we are checking equality by value only, not type.

`[]` represents an empty object, meaning `[]` and `0` have the same value.

In JavaScript, the value of any number greater than or equal to 1 is `true` and the value of 0 is `false`

Hope this helps

Comment: I understand everything up to the point "[] is also false and not false always returns true"?

Comment: This is part of boolean logic. `not false` equals `true`

Comment: Not false is `!false`, which is the opposite of `false`. The opposite of `false` is `true`. Therefore, `!false === true`.

Comment: Yeah but you kinda wrote "[] is FALSE and NOT FALSE"? I hope you understand what is confusing for me here.

Comment: Sorry, I ended up confusing myself here. I deleted that part